# Is it legal to download subtitles from youtube videos

Tags: terms-of-service

youtube videos have different types of subtitles, there is manual subtitles where the author writes his video's captions and uploads them, and there is the auto generated subtitles by youtube.

these subtitles can be downloaded in a geeky way,

Question: is it legal to download and use these subtitles whether they're auto generated or written by the author himself?

Comment: What do the terms of use/service say? There you go.

Answer (score 3):

On the face of it, transcripts are derivative work covered by copyright (even if automagically generated). You are allowed to use them if the use is fair use or if you comply with YouTube's terms of service.